# Combining two SQL queries to create an automatic procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, triggers

I've visited this forum many times to find answers to my questions but this is my first post. It's quite a specific question so couldn't find what I was looking for by searching.

My SQL is quite limited, i've just learnt what i've needed to as I've gone along but this is well over my head!

I run a free pub advertising website called Our-Pub.co.uk. Pubs can add their upcoming events to their individual pages as well as to a comprehensive Pub Guide. This is a completely free service, supporting both pubs and pub goers.
[www.our-pub.co.uk/TPG](http://www.our-pub.co.uk/TPG)

I use WordPress for my backend. Some of the events added are weekly / fortnightly events and I would like these to re-publish automatically. I was thinking this could be done by running a stored procedure to check for events that have passed and that are marked as weekly /fortnightly then adding 604800 (or 604800x2) seconds to them.

At the moment I have 2 SQL queries that I run, the first to find all events marked as weekly or fortnightly...

```
SELECT ID, post_title, wpr.object_id, wp_redhouseterms.name
FROM wp_redhouseterms
INNER JOIN wp_redhouseterm_taxonomy ON wp_redhouseterms.term_id = wp_redhouseterm_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_redhouseterm_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_redhouseterm_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_redhouseposts ON ID = wpr.object_id 
WHERE taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_redhouseterms.term_id=18
OR wp_redhouseterms.term_id=25
AND post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY `wpr`.`object_id` DESC
```

This returns a list of posts which are marked weekly / fortnightly with their post IDs and whether they are Weekly or Fortnightly events. I can then use this list of post IDs in my next query to return a list of existing event time values...

```
SELECT meta_id, post_id, meta_value 
FROM  `wp_redhousepostmeta` 
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'event_date_time'
AND (post_id LIKE  '1726'
OR post_id LIKE  '2296'
OR post_id LIKE  '1655'
OR post_id LIKE  '2373'
OR post_id LIKE  '2371'
OR post_id LIKE  '1650'
OR post_id LIKE  '1652'
OR post_id LIKE  '3036'
OR post_id LIKE  '1580'
OR post_id LIKE  '2375'
OR post_id LIKE  '4128'
OR post_id LIKE  '4132'
....etc....
)
```

I then update this list manually, adding either 604800 to weekly events or 1209600 to fortnightly events.

This was quite manageable at first but the list is growing and is now becoming a real pain to update!

Could any of you SQL wizzards advise me how I could combine these two scripts and put in a trigger to run at say 3am every morning to automatically update the events?

I have had a go myself but have had no luck, to be honest, I'm lost!

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks, Mark
Our-Pub.co.uk

Comment: Do you update the event_date_time of each event? or do you create a new event for each one?

Comment: I just update the existing event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `18` is weekly and `25` is fortnightly, the following should update the events appropriately:

```
UPDATE wp_redhousepostmeta rh
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, wt.term_id
    FROM wp_terms wt
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wt.term_id = wtt.term_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN wp_posts ON ID = wpr.object_id 
    WHERE taxonomy = 'category'
      AND (wt.term_id=18 OR wt.term_id=25)
      AND post_type = 'post'
    ) t ON rh.post_id = t.ID
SET rh.meta_value = rh.meta_value + CASE WHEN t.term_id = 18 THEN 604800
                                         WHEN t.term_id = 25 THEN 1209600 END
WHERE rh.meta_key = 'event_date_time';
```

Test it first by running the following and checking everything looks right:

```
SELECT t.id 
    ,t.term_id
    ,rh.meta_value
    ,rh.meta_value + CASE WHEN t.term_id = 18 THEN 604800
                          WHEN t.term_id = 25 THEN 1209600 END AS new_meta_value
FROM wp_redhousepostmeta rh
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, wt.term_id
    FROM wp_terms wt
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wt.term_id = wtt.term_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN wp_posts ON ID = wpr.object_id 
    WHERE taxonomy = 'category'
      AND (wt.term_id=18 OR wt.term_id=25)
      AND post_type = 'post'
    ) t ON rh.post_id = t.ID
WHERE rh.meta_key = 'event_date_time'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24a17/2)

Comment: Cheers for the speedy reply mate! Just trying it now but getting an error...

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_redhousepostmeta rh INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID, wt.term_id FROM w' at line 4

Comment: Hmm I don't get that same error, although I had the name of one of the columns wrong so hopefully that caused it. Try the query from the SQLFiddle link I just added to my answer.

Comment: Paste it into that SQLFiddle, run it, and paste the URL in here.

Comment: Sorry, think I may have confused things a bit! My WP tables all have the prefix wp_redhouse (Something I misunderstood when I set up the initial installation) but I remove the 'redhouse' bit from the table names in the first part of SQL i pasted (in an attempt to make it more readable!)
I've edited the original post with the actual SQL and table names...
Sorry about that!

The "SELECT" code works (when I change the table names) but still getting an error on the "UPDATE" code...

Comment: Ah my mistake, didn't realise the syntax for update was different between MySQL and SQLServer, the above query should now work (although the table names are still as before)

Comment: Absolute legend! That has worked perfectly! Thank you very much OGHaza! PM me your paypal email address and I'll buy you a pint! ;)
Cheers mate!

Comment: Mine's a kronenbourg mate. No problem, if you hit the green tick next to the answer it marks it as accepted and rewards me with some imaginary points.

Comment: Uh-Oh! Just noticed.. this script is updating all events with category 18 or 25 rather than events with category 18 or 25 AND have an event_time_date that less than the current time...

Comment: Gah, I don't have a database to test against but try `AND rh.meta_value < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` right at the bottom of that query. (I'm assuming it's a unix timestamp in that column, which it probably is, but recommend you test with the SELECT first)

Comment: And yet again, legend! :) Cheers mate, works perfectly!
I'll mark as solved and get you that virtual Kronenbourg in!
Thanks again mate, much appreciated!

Comment: Just found out that my hosting provider "One.com" dont allow cron jobs!
They've pointed me in the direction of setcronjob.com which i've had a look at and it seems like I need to create a PHP file on my server containing the SQL script.

Comment: I've had a search around for how to do this but most of what i've found seems to be far more complicated than what I need, leading me to believe what I need to do is relatively simple! Only thing is, this is deep into unknown territory for me (never even heard of a cron job until about an hour ago!) so if anyone could point me in the right direction (@OGHaza) it would be much appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: @Our-Pub I know almost no PHP unfortunately but to write the php script [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) looks fairly copy & paste friendly once you get your connection string right (which I've found is usually trial and error...). As for running it on a schedule, I'm not sure, but even if your host says they don't support cron I'd look into word press's [`wp_schedule_event`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) in case you can still use that (I'm not sure how to use it mind)

Comment: @Our-Pub, no one else but me will see that comment btw, so if you make an attempt at those 2 things you'll be in a pretty good place to ask a new question with your attempt so far.

Comment: Cheers OGHaza, I'll have a look into your suggestions and if I still cant figure it out, I'll post a new question!
Thanks again for your time! :)

Comment: Got it working mate! Thanks again for the push in the right direction!

Comment: @Our-Pub Ah nice one, much more painless than I expected ;)